# How can I call a method of the writer class when my Spring Batch Job complete?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch application and I have the following problem.

I have the definition of a single step Job containing this step:

```
@Bean
public Step readNotaryListStep(){
    return steps.get("readNotaryListStep").
            <Integer,Integer>chunk(1)  
            .reader(serviceItemReader())
            .processor(new NotaryDetailsEnrichProcessor(notaryService))
            .writer(new NotaryWriter(wpService))
            .build();
}

@Bean(name="updateNotaryListInfoJob")
public Job updateNotaryListInfoJob(){
    return jobs.get("updateNotaryListInfoJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(readNotaryListStep())
            .build();
}
```

It works fine. Basically it is reading from a reader, the output is processed and finnally it is written by the **new NotaryWriter(wpService)** that I create for the writer.

Ok...the following need has now emerged: after that the Job complete I need to call a method called **resetCounter()** defined into my **NotaryWriter** class (the class set for the writer section of my step).

Is it possible to implement a behavior like this? In case how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a `JobExecutionListener` or even `StepExecutionListener` which allow you to add a callback when a job and a step is completed. Both of them can be configured by the `listener()` on the `JobBuilder` and `StepBuilder` .

To allow the `JobExecutionListener` to call a method on the same instance of `NotaryWriter` that is configured in the step , you have to make `NotaryWriter` as a spring bean rather than create it manually , and make sure both the `JobExecutionListener` and the step refer to it.

Something likes :

```java
@Bean
public NotaryWriter notaryWriter(){
    return new NotaryWriter(wpService);
}
```

And inject it into both `JobExecutionListener` and the `Step` :

```java
@Component
public MyJobExecutionListener implements JobExecutionListener {
    
    @Autowired
    private NotaryWriter notaryWriter;

    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution){

    }

    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution){
        notaryWriter.resetCounter();
    }
}

@Bean
public Step readNotaryListStep(NotaryWriter notaryWriter){
    return steps.get("readNotaryListStep").
            .........
            .writer(notaryWriter)
            .build();
}
```

I just show you the general idea . You have to consider the scope of the `JobExecutionListener` and the `NotaryWriter` based on the things you want to do. It supports job scope , step scope or just application scope out of the box.

Because it seems to me that you actually want each step has their own instance of `NotaryWriter` such that its counter will not mess up with each other. If yes , you could simply define it as the `@StepScope` and do not need any listener :

```java
@Bean
@StepScope
public NotaryWriter notaryWriter(){
    return new NotaryWriter(wpService);
}

@Bean
public Step readNotaryListStep(NotaryWriter notaryWriter){
    return steps.get("readNotaryListStep").
            .........
            .writer(notaryWriter)
            .build();
}
```